# How to make Azure pipeline trigger itself a build when a snapshot dependency is build?

Tags: azure, maven, azure-devops, pom.xml, devops

We recently migrated from jenkins to azure devops, We have maven builds, jenkins had a feature to trigger build whenever snapshot dependency is built. 
I dont find any kind of feature with azure pipeline.

Comment: As far as I know, the answers below match the feature you need. For details,please refer to the Build completion triggers part in this docs:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic

Answer (score 0):

you need to navigate to the `triggers` section of the build and then click `+ Add` to add the dependency:

[image]

this will start the build after the selected build finished.

Comment: this is not a manual trigger. there is no such thing as a manual trigger

Comment: I have 50 maven build jobs, jenkins has plugin to trigger job if it's snapshot dependency is built, This way of triggering build is not efficient for this many jobs.

Comment: whats the difference, its the same. i mean, it might not be the same, but I cant understand from this description